# Extrude and Scale a window frame evenly

Tags: mesh, scale, extrude

Greeting all,

I'd like to extrude and scale it evenly around the whole object, rather than pulling it towards the object center. Instead of scaling lopsidedly, is this possible or is there and easier way to achieve this?

Cheers!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the solidify operator.

Or the solidify modifier, if you prefer that.

Or the Extrude Along Normals operator, which I’m not sure what the difference is between it and solidify.

FMI, try docs.blender.org for the latest manual and API docs.

Comment: OMG. I completely forgot that was even there. Boy is my face red. :/

Comment: @Bhaal Well, God is good. You should’ve seen the time I thought wagon in “wagon wheel effect” was a German name of the physicist who discovered it .

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard I was there  brain.exe crashes for all of us sometimes 